# Saving a vector in another vector and clearing the first one

Tags: java, vector

I have a technical issue in my coding. Below I am defining a vector of vectors:

```
        Vector<Vector<Integer>> uSupVec = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
        Vector<Integer> uSup = new Vector<Integer>();
        Boolean isRep = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <numSup ; i++) {
            uSup.clear();
            for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
                if (supName[i] == supName[l]) {
                    isRep = true;
                }}
            if (!isRep){uSup.add(i);}       
            for (int j = i+1; j < numSup; j++) {
                if (supName[i] == supName[j]) {
                        if (!isRep){uSup.add(j);}
                        }}
            isRep = false;
            uSupVec.add((Vector) uSup);
        }
```

My problem is whenever I am clearing my uSup vector, any vectors that are stored in uSupVec will be cleared. In each iteration I want to define a vector of some integer numbers and then store it in a vector of vectors and clear my vector to store new values and then store it again in my vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify

```
uSupVec.add((Vector) uSup);
```

to

```
uSupVec.add(new Vector(uSup));
```

Comment: `Vector uSup` is a reference to a Vector so when you add it to a Vector, you are adding a copy of the reference, not a copy of the collection. +1.